# Dask appropriate for my goal? ```Compute()``` taking very long

Tags: pandas, parallel-processing, dask

I am doing the following in Dask as the `df` dataframe has 7 million rows and 50 columns so pandas is extremely slow. However, I might not be using Dask correctly or Dask might not be appropriate for my goal. I need to do some preprocessing on the `df` dataframe, which is mainly creating some new columns. And then eventually saving the `df` (I am saving to csv but I have also tried parquet). However, before I save, I believe I have to do `compute()`. And `compute()` is taking very long -- I left it running for 3 hours and it still wasn't done. I tried to `persist()` throughout the calculations but `persist()` also took a long time. Is this expected with Dask given the size of my data? Could this be because of the number of partitions (I have 20 logical processor and dask is using 24 partitions -- I have 128 GB of memory if this helps too)? Is there something I could do to speed this up?

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd 
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from re import match
 from dask_ml.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

   df1 = dd.read_csv("data1.csv") 
df2 = dd.read_csv("data2.csv")
df = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on=['country', 'region'], right_on=['country', 'region'])              

df['actual__adj'] = (df['actual'] * df['travel'] + 809 * df['stopped']) / ( df['travel_time'] + df['stopped_time']) 
df['c_adj'] = 1 - df['actual_adj'] / df['free']
 df['stopped_tom'] = 1 * (df['stopped'] > 0)  

def func(df):     
     df = df.sort_values('region')     
     df['first_established'] = 1 * (df['region_d']==df['region_d'].min())            
     df['last_established'] = 1 * (df['region_d']==df['region_d'].max())     
     df['actual_established'] = df['noted_timeframe'].shift(1, fill_value=0)           
     df['actual_established_2'] = df['noted_timeframe'].shift(-1, fill_value=0)        
     df['time_1'] = df['time_book'].shift(1, fill_value=0)     
     df['time_2'] = df['time_book'].shift(-1, fill_value=0)     
     df['stopped_investing'] = df['stopped'].shift(1, fill_value=1)     
     return df  

df = df.groupby('country').apply(func).reset_index(drop=True)

df['actual_diff'] = np.abs(df['actual'] - df['actual_book'])
df['length_diff'] = np.abs(df['length'] - df['length_book']) 
 df['Investment'] = df['lor_index'].values * 1000 

df = df.compute().to_csv("path")
```

Comment: 7 million rows with Pandas in-memory is not too much according to my experience. I have 50 GB RAM and 7 million rows * 50 columns is very doable and very fast with Pandas.  There is also iterating technique that can speed up very fast.  Also downcast datatypes to minimize RAM access.  When it comes to 100M+ rows of data, I see that Pandas is unstable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving to csv or parquet will by default trigger computation, so the last line should be:

```py
df = df.to_csv("path_*.csv")
```

The asterisk is needed to specify the pattern of csv file names (each partition is saved into a separate file, unless you specify `single_file=True`).

My guess is that most of the computation time is spent on this step:

```py
df = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on=['country', 'region'], right_on=['country', 'region'])
```

If one of the dfs is small enough to fit in memory, then it would be good to keep it as a pandas dataframe, see further tips in the [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-joins.html).

Comment: Thank you. Doing ```to_csv()``` directly take slightly shorter. For some reference since I ran both in its entirety for curiosity. ```to_csv()``` take roughly 3 hours and ```compute().to_csv()``` take roughly 3.5 hours. However, if you want to save anything you eventually have to call compute, either directly or indirectly through to_csv() (which means save in local memory, correct me if I am wrong) so how did Dask help? I am very new to Dask and still not clear where the benefits are, since at some point the lazy evaluations/tasks will have to be computed if you want to save

Comment: `dask.compute()` will perform calculations on workers and transfer the data to your local machine. `.to_csv()` will save each partition in a separate file (without bringing data into memory). For example, if your final result is 1 TB and you have 100 workers with 10GB each, while your local memory is only 20GB, then there is no way of putting your final result in memory, but each worker can save the individual partitions on disk...

Comment: 7 million rows is not that much, so there is scope for optimizing `pandas` to work for this calculation, for example you don't seem to use all of 50 columns, so if you drop the unused columns, memory will become much less of a constraint.

Comment: I see, thanks for this. So Dask is ideal for RAM issues but if RAM is not too much of an issue (could fit data into RAM) but wanted to speed up pandas for example then something like https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html could be considered -- or like you say optimize pandas for both speed and memory

Comment: RAM is the main consideration, but it's also good for workflows that need to scale across files/parameters (e.g. grid search). Dask developers recommend pandas, if data fits in RAM (the first recommendation here: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html). For your code sample, it seems like there is some redundant columns (which take up memory) and potentially redundant calculations (e.g. perhaps some of the calculations could be done at the 'country' aggregation, which would reduce the number of rows)...